# What does this root represent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Three point charges $q$, $2q$ and $8q$ are placed on a 9cm wire and I have to minimize the potential energy. 
[image]
On writing $U$, doing $dU/dx=0$ and solving the resultant quadratic equation, I get two roots: $x= 3$ (where the field cancels out) and $x = -9$. Clearly, at $x = -9$, the two fields add up and don't give the minimum potential energy. *What does this $x = -9$ root represent, and why am I getting it as one of the roots?*

If it represents the maxima, why wouldn't the maxima be at x = 0 or x = 9 as over there the potential energy would tend to infinity

Comment: Can you draw the arrangement of your charges. I'm struggling to reproduce your answer of $x=3$.

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please show your calculation.

Comment: Edited and added a diagram. I hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have written the potential energy as (ignoring constants):

$$ U(x) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{8}{9-x} $$

If you graph this it looks like:

[image: V(x)]

There is a minimum at $x=3$ and there is a maximum at $x=-9$. I've shown these by the arrows, though the maximum at $x=-9$ isn't very obvious with the vertical scale I've used.

The reason you're getting a maximum at $x=-9$ is because there's a mistake in your equation for the potential energy. It should be:

$$ U(x) = \frac{2}{|x|} + \frac{8}{|9-x|} $$

And if you graph this it looks like:

[image: V(x)]

Note that the maximum at $x=-9$ has now disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the charge $2q$ a distance of $9 \, \rm cm$ from the $8q$ charge and placed the $q$ charge a distance $x$ from the $2q$ charge?

So you are trying to minimise a function of the form $y=\dfrac{4}{9-x} + \dfrac 1 x$.

When you differentiate this function and put the derivative equal to zero you get two roots of a quadratic $x=+3$ and $x=-9$.
To check which is a minimum you have to take the second derivative which identifies $x=+3$ as a (local) minimum and $x=-9$ as a (local) maximum.

Here is the output from WolframAlpha which shows the result graphically.

[image]

Comment: why wouldn't the maxima be at x = 0 or x = 9 as over there the potential energy would tend to infinity